# how to hook a Windows API function inside the IAT of a running process and replace it with a dummy function?

Tags: c, portable-executable

My goal is to perform an IAT hook. I want to replace `LoadLibraryA` (LLA) with my own function `ModifiedLLA`.

I dug my way through the PE format, and I was able to locate the function names for each imported DLL file.

Consider this will be my replacement function:

```
DWORD ModifiedLLA(char* str){
    printf("test\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Consider the following code inside the main function:

```
...

//IAT & ILTs have been assigned previously

//Declare pointer to our own function
DWORD(WINAPI *procPtr)(char*);
procPtr = ModifiedLLA;

while(ilt->u1.AddressOfData){
    namedata = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)((DWORD_PTR)imagebase +
                 (DWORD)ilt->u1.AddressOfData);

    //We have found the LoadLibraryA function.
    if(strcmp(namedata->Name, "LoadLibraryA") == 0){


        //Here we must replace the original LoadLibraryA with procPtr;


        break;
    }
    ilt++;
    alt++;
}
...
```

The question is "how I can assign `procPtr` to the LLA address"?

I read that when the `IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG` is not set, the address of `LoadLibraryA` becomes `iat->u1.Function + namedata`.

However, I am not sure what data type I should cast `(DWORD_PTR)namedata + (DWORD)iat->u1.Function` to. I tried to cast it to a `DWORD_PTR`. When I try to assign procPtr to the address, I get errors, such as:
invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘DWORD_PTR’ {aka ‘long long unsigned int’})

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate the IAT of a process that is running (or at least suspended)? Or are you just trying to manipulate the file contents of a PE file?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Of a process that is running. The code is manipulating the IAT of the same process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Apparently it's as easy as `iat->u1.Function = (ULONGLONG)procPtr`

Thus, the code becomes:

```
//IAT & ILTs have been assigned previously

//Declare pointer to our own function
DWORD(WINAPI *procPtr)(char*);
procPtr = ModifiedLLA;

while(ilt->u1.AddressOfData){
    namedata = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)((DWORD_PTR)imagebase +
                 (DWORD)ilt->u1.AddressOfData);

    //We have found the LoadLibraryA function.
    if(strcmp(namedata->Name, "LoadLibraryA") == 0){

        iat->u1.Function = (ULONGLONG)procPtr;

        break;
    }
    ilt++;
    alt++;
}
...
```

I hope this will help some other folks as well.

Comment: `ULONGLONG` is 64-bit on the Microsoft Windows platform. However, your question does not specify whether the process you are running is 32-bit or 64-bit. Therefore, this answer only applies to 64-bit processes.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel That's a good point. in 32-bit iat->u1.function is defined as a DWORD. What would be the better approach?

Comment: Good question. The only answer I can think of is to use conditional compiliation using the preprocessor, depending on whether the macro [`_WIN64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019) is defined, like this `#ifdef _WIN64`.

Comment: Or just use `(DWORD_PTR)`, as above.